# Session frozen after an update and restart?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, freeze

I have done the updates proposed by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the software updater then proposed to restart.

So I did and after I typed the password for my user it never shows my desktop. It looks like this:

[image: Frozen desktop]

It does the same in guest mode...

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Is there a way to to go back one update if I have not done a snapshot or backup?

*additional info*:I work on a VM under Windows 7.

Comment: Are you using NVidia?

Comment: How to see that? Actually I am testing [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/) and the first part did not fix it... I'll post another comment soon after the test of the second part

Comment: phew... it seems that it was that problem... Right now I want to see if I do some more restarts it does the same, or it has been fixed. Anyway, why does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Ubuntu Nvidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer Nvidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.